# iOS 14.0 and above weird autolayout behaviour

Tags: ios, autolayout

on iOS 14.0 and above if i have two textfields side by side with equal width and equal height constraint , when we try to push a controller containing these textfields the entire UI freezes this is happening on iphone 7 plus and 8 plus devices and randomly on some XR device not all, works on other devices.

while debugging the called viewcontroller is executing the didload didappear functions but the viewcontroller doesn't get pushed, i.e the UI deosn't appear on screen, it displays the parent views UI and the entire app freezes, no crash.

I am using xibs

Works perfectly fine on iOS 13 and below.
Anyone can shed any light on this.
I am using ibdesignables for the textfield

Comment: This is hard to say without any code.  If the app does not crash but is still not responding, it seems like you are having some "invisible" view on top which might eat up all user events. Try to reduce the problem by removing / disabling the constraints one by one, removing the textfields etc. until the problem does not occur. Did you debug your app and the view hierarchy?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue (i removed the constraint and added a stackview which fixed the issue) , maybe i didn't phrase my question properly, my doubt is why is this happening. and that too on certain phones not all.